# i need load proxies from a txt file in pytho proxy settings windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want a code to press the save button python
can you help me
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rznQ.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rznQ.png%5D)

```
import winreg as winreg
INTERNET_SETTINGS = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings',
    0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)

def set_key(name, value):
    _, reg_type = winreg.QueryValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name)
    winreg.SetValueEx(INTERNET_SETTINGS, name, 0, reg_type, value)

    set_key('ProxyEnable', 1)
    set_key('ProxyOverride', u'*.local;<local>')  # Bypass the proxy for localhost


 with open('proxies.txt','r') as fin:
        proxy = fin.readline()
    with open('vpn.txt', 'r') as fin:
        data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
    with open('vpn.txt', 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(data[1:])

set_key('ProxyServer', u'95.164.233.251:5609')
```

Comment: The 'u' is how one specified a Unicode string in Python 2.  Which Python are you using?  You have both tagged, and the code is different.

Comment: yes anther code
i need help 
I want to read the proxy from a txt file
 When u delete it, the code is valid but it doesn't work
set_key('ProxyServer', (proxy))
It didn't work because the letter u . was deleted
i need help

Comment: Can you edit the question because I didn't get what you want!

Comment: I edited the question, hope you understand me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want a code to press the save button python can you help me https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rznQ.png]