# debugging the code How do I search for an macaddres in a group of mac addresses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, mac-address

mac=
00-FF-2E-3B-D1-0B

00-FF-70-6B-82-78
04-EA-56-70-42-9D
04-EA-56-70-42-9E
06-EA-56-70-42-9D
00-D8-61-08-71-E7
00-FF-6A-96-4D-66

How to compare mac addresses
In one address to fulfill the condition

```
import os
for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"):
        if line.lstrip().startswith('Physical Address'):

            mac = line.split(':')[1].strip()

            print(mac)



user_mac = '00-FF-2E-3B-D1-0B'
if user_mac in mac :




print("work")




else:
print("not work:)")
```

Comment: Can you split mac-addresses to help you! `00-FF-70-6B-82-78 04-EA-56-70-42-9D 04-EA-56-70-42-9E 06-EA-56-70-42-9D 00-D8-61-08-71-E7 00-FF-6A-96-4D-66`

Answer (score 0):

Just check for a match while you're reading the lines:

```
import os
user_mac = '00-FF-2E-3B-D1-0B'
found = False
for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"):
    if line.lstrip().startswith('Physical Address'):
        mac = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        if mac == user_mac:
            found = True
            break
if found:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: thanks you very mush
It works

Comment: hi pro can help me
https://stackoverflow.com/q/70887076/16621341

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a mac or a string try to add an empty list, append all those strings to this list and search for it using a for loop.

```
import os

list = []

for line in os.popen("ipconfig /all"):
    if line.lstrip().startswith('Physical Address'):
        mac = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        list.append(mac)

mac = "00-FF-2E-3B-D1-0B"
for s in list:
    if s == mac:
        print("work")
        break
    print("not work:)")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70887076/16621341